# 'RecursionError' in a for loop

Tags: python

I have tried to implement a flatten function to even flatten strings but got an error for Recursion. Could someone help resolve this puzzle?

```
def flatten(items):
  for x in items:
      if isinstance(x, Iterable):
         yield from flatten(x)
      else:
         yield x

items = [2, [3, 4, [5, 6], 7], 8, 'abc']

for x in flatten(items):
    print(x)
```

I was expecting to print '2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, a, b, c'; but instead, I got '2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 and a RecursionError. I think the 'abc' is also 'Iterable', so why the code doesn't work?

Thank you!

Comment: `'abc'` is a sequence that contains `'a'` as its first element, which is a sequence that contains `'a'` as its first element, which is a sequence that contains `'a'` as its first element...  Basically, you have to special-case strings whenever you recursively explore any structure that might contain them.

Comment: I would think that flattening those items should give `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'abc']` since "to flatten" means to remove nesting and one doesn't typically think of a list of strings as being a nested data structure.

Comment: A related problem: how would you want to handle a cyclic reference like `x = []; x.append(x)`? Or worse, `x = []; y = []; x.append(y); y.append(x)`?

Comment: @jasonharper, very good insight! I didn't realize that 'a' itself is also iterable

Answer (score 3):

The problem as jasonharper pointed is that 'a' is an iterable element which contains 'a' and so on. You can however, rewrite the code with another if before the `yield from flatten(x)` something like

```
from collections.abc import Iterable
def flatten(items):
  for x in items:
      if isinstance(x, Iterable):
         if len(x)==1:
             yield next(iter(x))
         else: 
             yield from flatten(x)
      else:
         yield x

items = [2, [3, 4, [5, 6], 7], 8, 'abc']

for x in flatten(items):
    print(x)
```

Comment: Not all iterables support `len`. You'd have to check `isinstance(x, Sized)` first.

Comment: (This also would incorrectly yield `[1]`, not `1`, when `x == [1]`.)

Comment: The idea that `x == next(iter(x))` is weird enough that it's probably safe to assume that `str` and `bytes` are the only classes that satisfy the equality.

Comment: @chepner I agree, I did not thought that there are iterables with no len but you are right, I should have written x[1] and not x. I don't get the last comment.

Comment: It's one thing for `x` and `next(iter(x))` to have the same *type* (consider `x == [[1]]`), another for `x` to be the same *value*. (`'a' == next(iter('a'))`, but `[[1]] != next(iter([1]))`.

Comment: Basically, the idea is that the elements yielded by an iterator should be "less iterable" than the iterator itself. While that's not true for *some* values of type `list` (for example, `x = []; x.append(x)`, since `x is x[0]`), it's not true for *any* value of type `str` or `bytes`.

Comment: So to sum up, I should have written `if isinstance(x, Sized) and len(x)==1`? Or I am still not considering something?

Comment: That's necessary, but not sufficient. Just as you can't assume that all iterables support `len`, you can't assume they support indexing, either. You could check for `Sequence`, which requires both `__len__` and `__getitem__` be defined. That's why I used `next(iter(x))` above, not `x[0]`.

Comment: And this is why I think it's easier (and probably good enough) to simply hard-code a check for `str` or `bytes`, rather than try to figure out what more general class of `str`-like types need to be special-cased.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you're exceeding the limit of the call stack I won't get into the nitty-gritty here but, you can read this article: https://towardsdatascience.com/python-stack-frames-and-tail-call-optimization-4d0ea55b0542

Recursion is a tricky problem to get right, it's often best to avoid it when possible in my own personal opinion. If you refactor your code to use a minimal amount of recursion and use the built-in iter() function on string values it works without exiting the call stack like so.

```
    from collections.abc import Iterable

def flatten(items):
  for x in items:
      if isinstance(x, str):
         yield from iter(x)
      elif isinstance(x, Iterable):
         yield from flatten(x)
      else:   
         yield x

items = [2, [3, 4, [5, 6], 7], 8, 'abc']

for x in flatten(items):
    print(x)
```